# Two identical links behave differently while parsing username from them

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've created a script in python to fetch username from a webpage. I've used two identical links to see how the script behaves. The script can parse the username of the first link but failed while going for the second link and as a result it throws `AttributeError`.

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = (
    "https://twitter.com/fabogeek",
    "https://twitter.com/radio702"
)

for link in links:
    res = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    username = soup.select_one("div[dir='ltr']:contains('@') > span").text
    print(username)
```

Current output:

```
@Jeezy
AttributeError
```

Expected output:

```
@Jeezy
@Radio702
```

> How can I get username from the second link as well using requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. Your `select_one()` didn't get the second link, so it was returning `None`.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = (
    "https://twitter.com/fabogeek",
    "https://twitter.com/radio702"
)

for link in links:
    res = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    username = soup.find("b", {'class':'u-linkComplex-target'}).text
    print(username)
```

> Out[1]: 
>   FaboGeek 
>   Radio702

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be working. Could you help me find out the class that you have used in your suggested script as I can't locate it in page source? Thanks.

Comment: RIght-click and inspect element of the Twitter handle: `<b class="u-linkComplex-target">FaboGeek</b>`

Comment: this is what I get `<span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">@FaboGeek</span>` when I right click on `@FaboGeek` (right under 2$ Fabo) and inspect element of it.